# SEVERE: regression in latest systemd update for Raspbian Stretch

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've recently updated my Stretch system and this got me version 232-25+deb9u6 of systemd.

A very nasty side effect is that my /var/log/auth.log gets flooded with stuff like:

```
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 su[29165]: Successful su for root by root
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 su[29165]: + ??? root:root
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 su[29165]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 su[29165]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 su[29165]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Nov 30 07:13:34 rpi2-2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 30 07:13:35 rpi2-2 sudo:       pi : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su - -c echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

This seems to have been fixed by a more recent version of systemd (see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10832) but I haven't been able to build that version on my own.

This is a showstopper since I have some code that runs 'su' twice per second, causing auth.log to quickly fill up the root partition.

How can get the latest systemd binary for Raspbian Stretch, or an older version that doesn't have this problem?

Comment: According to the [changelog of 232-25+deb9u6](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/s/systemd/systemd_232-25+deb9u6_changelog) there doesn't seem to be any changes in logging... Are you sure this is really related to systemd?

Comment: The [PR #10832](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10832) you mentioned only affects the line in the middle (`pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session`), so I'd think the other lines would still be there even with that patch on...

Comment: Also, file `/var/log/auth.log` is typically managed by syslog (rsyslogd, or whatever implementation of syslog you're currently running...) Are you sure there were no changes to syslog in this last upgrade that caused it to start logging to this file?

Comment: According to the logs, you’re running `sudo su` as root, which means neither sudo nor su are necessary.

Comment: the command I need to run as root from the script that runs twice per second is `echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness 2>&1`. If use only `sudo` I get "command not found", if I use only `su` I get prompted for the root password...

Answer (score 1):

You have several questions here, actually and I will try and address each. Note that the solution here seems to be to not use `su` as pointed out by Stephen Kitt in the comments.

I will address some other aspects.

How do you prepare a debian-based system for building from source, example: systemd (I would recommend to do this in a sandbox system such as a VM few times first)

`$ sudo apt-get build-dep systemd`

Now, assuming the version you wish to build is not a lot newer than the one you have, the dependencies are often the same, this holds true for patch-releases of systemd. The above command will get all the packages you need to build systemd, except, of course, systemd itself. Note that below, we are going to grab the latest and greatest systemd, note sure all prerequisites are met.

You then get the sources and build; systemd is on github, so you need git to get the sources.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
$ git clone https://github.com/systemd/systemd.git
```

How you exactly build the source depends on the build system used by the developers of the software in question, systemd uses meson. I saw that when I wen to https://github.com/systemd/systemd, I scrolled down, there they have info on the project.

I saw this line:

> Information about build requirements is provided in the README file.

and read the README file, always a good idea!

```
$ sudo apt-get install meson
$ git clone https://github.com/systemd/systemd.git
$ meson systemd/ && ninja -C systemd
$ cd systemd; sudo ninja install
```

How to configure retention of logs, so they do not fill up your drive:

Here, you need to configure logrotation for rsyslog. The configuration for logrotate lives in `/etc/logrotate.d`, the file we want is `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

Access the docs first:

```
  $ man logrotate.conf
  $ man logrotate
```

Ok, so now we have read the docs, we know that the keyword to rotate logs is `rotate`, `size` specifies when to rotate to the next file, `compress` compresses the rotated file, `mail` mails it (optional), I want the file to be rotated, so I set `mailfirst`.

My `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` looks like:

```
[...]
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
[...]
```

To configure logrotate for `/var/log/auth`:

```
[...]
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
{
  rotate 10
  size 100M
  compress
  mail jdoe@example.com
  mailfirst
}
/var/log/user.log
[...]
```

This will keep max 10 files of `100Mb` so almost 1Gb, as soon as a file reaches 100M, it is  compressed and emailed to jdoe@example.com. By default, rotatelog is run daily via cron, you might want to run it hourly. `man crontab`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate writeup. Building systemd with the documented command line fails with `Meson encountered an error in file /home/pi/systemd/systemd-master/meson_options.txt, line 165, column 53:
Expecting rparen got id.`. Log rotation is already enabled, but given the speed `auth.log` grows, I'm afraid even daily rotate would suffice ;-) I've bitten the bullet and replaced all the `sudo su - -c` in my shell scripts with calling a setuid root binary that does the work (of setting/getting the settings for the Raspberry Pi's LCD display).

Comment: Sorry for the systemd build failure, it appears something is broken in the systemd sources (I dunno, master should never have a broken build), the stable release appeared to be too old. You could also set hourly rotate, or even every minute.... but removing `sudo` was the correct approach! `auth.log` is an important log file!!